# Multilevel JSON data using jquery

Tags: json

can any one tell me how to access data from "item2" from the below json?

**JSON**

```
item1: [
  { "location": [
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "fileName": value }
    ],
   "links": [
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "fileName": value },
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "fileName": value },
      {"latitude": value, "longitude": value, "fileName": value }
    ]
  }   
],
item2: [ //repeat of above ]
```

Comment: can you show what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you to iterate the `item2` from your json

```
<script language="javascript" >

document.writeln("<h2>JSON array object</h2>");

var books = { "Java" : [ 
      { "Name"  : "Java is Simple", "price" : 500 },
      { "Name"  : "The Complete Reference", "price" : 600 }
   ],                       
   "Spring"  : [
      { "Name"  : "Spring is mvc", "price" : 300 }, 
      { "Name"  : "Basics Spring", "price" : 200 }
   ]    
}    

var i = 0
document.writeln("<table border='2'><tr>");
for(i=0;i<books.Java.length;i++)
{ 
   document.writeln("<td>");
   document.writeln("<table border='1' width=100 >");
   document.writeln("<tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td width=50>"
   + books.Java[i].Name+"</td></tr>");
   document.writeln("<tr><td><b>Price</b></td><td width=50>"
   + books.Java[i].price +"</td></tr>");
   document.writeln("</table>");
   document.writeln("</td>");
}

for(i=0;i<books.Spring.length;i++)
{
   document.writeln("<td>");
   document.writeln("<table border='1' width=100 >");
   document.writeln("<tr><td><b>Name</b></td><td width=50>"
   + books.Spring[i].Name+"</td></tr>");
   document.writeln("<tr><td><b>Price</b></td><td width=50>"
   + books.Spring[i].price+"</td></tr>");
   document.writeln("</table>");
   document.writeln("</td>");
}
document.writeln("</tr></table>");
</script>
```